# using .htaccess to block tor servers

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a large list of tor servers, maybe 2,000+ servers that I would like to ban from registering accounts on my site. Is it viable to block the entire list I have in an .htaccess file or will this cause the server to slow down in the same way having thousands of hosts in iptables will?

Is there another alternative? I have captcha already but bots aren't the problem. The problem is users using tor to circumvent bans.

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: i think freenode blocks tor, you might ask on the moderators forum how they do it

Comment: my OS is centOS.  Since I only needed this block for the registration page, what I did was this: when someone tries to go to the create account page, it redirects them to a page that checks their IP against a list of 4000+ tor entry/exit nodes and if it doesn't match, sets a session that allows them to register an account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your htaccess file

```
order deny,allow
deny from x.x.x.x
deny from x.x.x.
allow from all
```

The alterative (and probably best) way is adding a DROP rule in your iptables firewall, which will keep the IP addressess away from your server.